# Not able to remember the user id

Tags: routes, users

I am new to Drupal. I have created a menu on user page to edit the account settings as `user/uid/edit`.

I just want to know how to replace `uid` with the user id of current user.

Comment: No need to remember actually. Drupal will populate the edit link as it supposed to be.

Comment: @NikhilMohan I'm confused. Could you please explain how will Drupal do it automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced a similar problem in the recent past and found two solutions for the same.

### Short solution

Install [Me alias](http://drupal.org/project/me) module, and then replace your *uid* with *me*, and the module will replace *me* with the *uid* of respective user.

### Long solution

Install [Menu token](http://drupal.org/project/menu_token) module and use token to replace the path of the menu. Go to edit menu and in the path, do the following

[image: snapshot]

Comment: the short solution worked for me! thank you!
will try the other solution also and let you know about the results..